# When does $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda B\mathbf{v}$ admit a basis of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be Hermitian matrices, and consider the so-called *generalized eigenvalue problem*
$$A\mathbf{v} = \lambda B\mathbf{v}$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is called a *generalized eigenvalue of $A$ with respect to $B$*, and $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is the corresponding *generalized eigenvector*. It seems to be a well-known fact that if $B$ is positive-definite, then this problem admits a family of solutions $(\lambda_1, \mathbf{v}_1), \dots, (\lambda_n, \mathbf{v}_n)$ with $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n$ linearly independent, but I've never actually seen a proof. (See, for example, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem), whose references are unfortunately unavailable to me.) Does anyone know how the argument goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Note that $A \sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{B} v = \lambda \sqrt{B} \sqrt{B}v$ and
so $\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{B} v = \lambda  \sqrt{B}v$.

The matrix $\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1}$ is Hermitian.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that you can always take the square root of a positive-definite matrix. Thanks!

Comment: Another curious and sometimes useful result is that if $A,B$ are Hermitian and $B>0$ then there is a basis in which $A,B$ are both diagonal. Also see http://mathoverflow.net/q/129514/31729.